# How to tabdo all the visible buffers without changing view of the current tab?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim, vimscript-lua

My init.vim code:

```
cd ~/Documents/cp
nnoremap <leader>lcd :tabdo lcd %:p:h<cr>
```

suppose, i have 4 tabs opened in nvim 
via using `nvim -p A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp D.cpp`

```
A.cpp
B.cpp
C.cpp
D.cpp
```

When I need to temporarily change the 4 tab's current directory as the default one, 
typing `\lcd` changes all the visible tabs to local current directory.

But `tabdo` has a side effect. 
It helps to use a specific command in all opened tabs 
while doing that, vim goes to the last tab (which i don't want)

**So How can i tabdo all buffers without changing view of the current tab?** 
I didn't find any simple solution.

PS: I've checked some resources. 
(1) [Windo and restore current window](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Windo_and_restore_current_window) 
(2) [How to apply a setting in all open tabs and windows?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12068/36876)

but didn't find for `tabdo` command in 1st resource

tried the 2nd resource code, but it goes to the last tab and removes it & turns it into current buffer 
if i have A.cpp opened as current tab, 2nd resource code will do this 
`A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp A.cpp` (removes `D.cpp`)

Comment: Complete aside: forcibly setting the directory in your vimrc (init.vim) is something I really recommend against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save and restore the current tab around the `:tabdo` operation. You can use `tabpagenr()` to get the position of the current tab and later you can pass that number to `:tabnext` to change back to this tab. This is better done in a function, since you can easily run multiple commands and also use a local variable to store the current tab number.

```
function! TabLcd()
    let current_tab = tabpagenr()
    tabdo lcd %:p:h
    execute 'tabnext' current_tab
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>lcd :call TabLcd()<cr>
```

Note that you need `:execute` for the `:tabnext` in order to pass the count with the tab number from a variable.

Comment: it works.. thank you very much :)