# Conversion in Lua: how to tabdo all the visible buffers without changing view of the current tab?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Related to this post, [how to tabdo all the visible buffers without changing view of the current tab?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31903/36876)

```
function! TabLcd()
    let current_tab = tabpagenr()
    tabdo <commands>
    execute 'tabnext' current_tab
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>lcd :call TabLcd()<cr>
```

The code is written in Vimscript. I want to implement it in Lua.

Can anyone help me convert this?

Comment: At first glance your conversion looks ok. What is wrong about you conversion? What are the symptom of failure? What is it suppose to do and what it is actually doing or not doing?

Comment: `\lcd` command doesn't work but `\cd` works.

Comment: What are the symptoms about `\lcd` failure?

Comment: Huh, it worked. I didn't have much belief in myself. I forgot to mention the feature. You can see the related post. My permanent local directory is `~/Documents/cp`. If I want to change it to a temporary local directory. Then pressing `\lcd` executes this command `tabdo lcd %:p:h` in all opened tabs. Mnemonic `lcd` equal to Local Current Directory.

Comment: In my tests it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yep, mine worked fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua format

```lua
function TabLcd()
    local current_tab = vim.fn.tabpagenr()
    vim.cmd("tabdo <commands>")
    vim.cmd("execute 'tabnext' " .. current_tab)
end

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<leader>lcd', ':lua TabLcd()<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

1. `function TabLcd()` defines a Lua function named *TabLcd*.
2. `local current_tab = vim.fn.tabpagenr()`: It stores the current tab
   page number in the current_tab variable using a Neovim built-in
   function `vim.fn.tabpagenr()`.
3. `vim.cmd("tabdo <commands>")`: This line executes `<commands>` in all open tabs. You would replace  with the
   specific commands you want to run in each tab. For example, if you
   want to run `:command1` in each tab, you would use `vim.cmd("tabdo command1")`.
4. `vim.cmd("execute 'tabnext' " .. current_tab)`: After executing the
   commands in all tabs, it switches back to the original tab also defined as current_tab.
5. Set any keymap (in this case `\lcd`), And you're a go.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition would be:

```lua
function TabLcd()
    local current_tab = vim.fn.tabpagenr()
    vim.cmd("tabdo lcd %:p:h")
    vim.cmd("execute 'tabnext' " .. current_tab)
end

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<leader>lcd', ':lua TabLcd()<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Comment: Yeah, my code worked fine. I have submitted the solution for a general format.